# How to set focus on a TextView when an Activity starts?

Tags: android

There are an EditText and a TextView in my Activity. I want to set focus on the TextView when the Activity starts. I used the following code:

```
    TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text_vew);
    myTextView.setFocusable(true);
    myTextView.setOnClickListener(this);
    myTextView.requestFocus();
```

But the code doesn't work. The EditText always receives focus when the activity starts.

Can anyone help?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is expected when you start the Activity using the touch screen. When in "touch mode," only a couple of Views (EditText and ListView) can receive the focus. If you start your application using the trackball you will see the focus on the TextView. What you are seeing is the correct and expected result.

Comment: How to do the opposite. For example I have a numeric editfield as first ui object, and always receives focus and popups the keyboard. I don't want the keyboard to popup.

Comment: So, I need to set the TextView to be focusable in touch mode?

Answer (score 13):

I came across with your question now. Maybe after 2 years you have found a solution. But I write it here for the others that will come across with this in the future. The only thing you have to do is to go to the `AndroidManifest.xml`, find the `Activity` in which you want  this behaviour and add this `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"`. So, at the start of your `Activity` no keyboard will be shown, until you touch the `EditText` object.

Answer (score 12):

If anyone is still wondering, you can use the following in your layout xml to make a textview focusable in touch mode:

```
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Answer (score 9):

In order to request focus to TextView you need to set `focusable="true"` and `focusableInTouchMode="true"` as follows:

```
 <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Heading"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true">
                <requestFocus />
     </TextView>
```

Answer (score 2):

Add the TextView Property in layout

```
android:focusable="false"
```

It's work for me.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

```
EditText mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_text);
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_text_vew);

mEditText.setFocusable(false);  
myTextView.setFocusable(true);
```

This takes focus off of the EditText **and** puts it on the TextView.

Answer (score 0):

You can set focus to any widget or a TextView from the xml of the activity. Just add **requestFocus**  before the TextView end.

```
<AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView2"
        android:layout_width="470dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="90dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/textView2"
        android:ems="10"
        android:textColor="#455A64"
        android:textColorHint="#455A64"
        android:textSize="27sp">

        <requestFocus />
    </AutoCompleteTextView>
```