# Unable to set accessibility focus on title textview

Tags: android, accessibility

I have an EditText on an activity that requests focus when the activity launches. This is great for users who do not have TalkBack enabled. However, for accessibility (i.e. for users who have TalkBack enabled), I need to set the focus on the titlebar of the screen, instead of the EditText.

I have tried several things but have been unsuccessful at setting the focus on the titlebar's textview (I have checked that titleTextView does not return null):

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

TextView titleTextView = null;
//get the tool bar's title TextView
try
{
    Class<?> toolbarClass = Toolbar.class;
    Field titleTextViewField = toolbarClass.getDeclaredField("mTitleTextView");
    titleTextViewField.setAccessible(true);
    titleTextView = (TextView)titleTextViewField.get(toolbar);
}
catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

if (titleTextView != null)
{
    titleTextView.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED);
    AccessibilityManager manager = (AccessibilityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE);
    if (manager.isEnabled())
    {
        AccessibilityEvent e = AccessibilityEvent.obtain(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_FOCUSED);
        e.setSource(titleTextView);
        e.setEventType(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED);
        e.setClassName(getClass().getName());
        e.setPackageName(getPackageName());
        e.getText().add("Message");
        manager.sendAccessibilityEvent(e);          
    }
```

The titleTextView never receives focus when TalkBack is on.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496720/how-to-set-focus-on-a-textview-when-an-activity-starts

Comment: @FishStix: I am wondering if it is possible to set the focus only for accessibility. I only want the focus to be on the toolbar if the user has TalkBack on. For users who do not have TalkBack enabled, I want the focus to be on the EditText. The link you posted does not contain the answer to my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to fix this by moving the code into the if block to only execute the code in the block if the user has TalkBack enabled. Namely, accessibilityManager.isEnabled() will only evaluate to true if TalkBack is on:

```
AccessibilityManager am = (AccessibilityManager)getSystemService(Context.ACCESSIBILITY_SERVICE);
if (am.isEnabled())
{
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(actionBar);
    toolbar.setFocusable(true);
    toolbar.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    try
    {               
        Class<?> toolbarClass = Toolbar.class;
        Field titleTextViewField = toolbarClass.getDeclaredField("mTitleTextView");
        titleTextViewField.setAccessible(true);
        TextView titleTextView = (TextView)titleTextViewField.get(toolbar);
        titleTextView.setFocusable(true);
        titleTextView.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    }
    catch (NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException e)
    {               
        e.printStackTrace();            
    }
    toolbar.sendAccessibilityEvent(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED);
    AccessibilityEvent e = AccessibilityEvent.obtain(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED);
    e.setSource(toolbar);
    e.setEventType(AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED);
    e.setClassName(getClass().getName());
    e.setPackageName(getPackageName());
    am.sendAccessibilityEvent(e);
}
```

Comment: Why does it not work by default? Whats the reason that we need to override the behavior like this?

Comment: I haven't tested this recently, but it's related to the EditText automatically requesting focus regardless of whether or not TalkBack is on.