# Xamarin Forms Dependency Service: change accessibility focus after button click

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, view, dependencies, accessibility

What I want is to be able to set the accessibility focus to a particular element after the click of a button. I tried to achieve that using dependency service, but it doesn't work, I think due to the fact that I try to convert a Forms.View to an Android.View, but I am not sure if it is the problem, maybe I am doing something else wrong. Do you know how to do that, using dependency service or whatever else?

What I tried, (for the moment only on Android):

MainPage:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage

{
    Button b1;
    Button b2;
    IAccessibilityFocusService service;

    public MainPage()
    {
    InitializeComponent();

            service = DependencyService.Get<IAccessibilityFocusService(DependencyFetchTarget.NewInstance);

            b1 = new Button
            {
                Text = "BUTTON 1",
                BackgroundColor = Color.Blue,
            };

            b2 = new Button
            {
                Text = "BUTTON 2",
            };
            stacklayout.Children.Add(b1);
            stacklayout.Children.Add(b2);
            b1.Clicked += Mybutton_Clicked;
     }

     private async void Mybutton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
           Console.WriteLine("PIPPO clicked");
           service.ChangeAccessibilityFocus(b2);
     }
}
```

IAccessibilityFocusService:

`public interface IAccessibilityFocusService
 {
       void ChangeAccessibilityFocus(View v);

 }`

AndroidAccessibilityFocus:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(CustomViewAccessibility.Droid.AccessibilityFocus))]
public class AndroidAccessibilityFocus : IAccessibilityFocusService
{

    public void ChangeAccessibilityFocus(View v)
    {
            //first I convert the Forms.Veiw to the native android view, so that I can invoke sendAccessibilityEvent on that view.
            Platform.CreateRendererWithContext(v, Android.App.Application.Context).View.SendAccessibilityEvent(EventTypes.ViewFocused); 

    }
}
```

Comment: I try your code and it doesn't work, so I search some info and try to provide one solution, but I fail. I also find one thread, may be helpful to you, that you can take a look:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38447493/unable-to-set-accessibility-focus-on-title-textview

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your service before it can be resolved.

```
using Xamarin.Forms;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(AndroidAccessibilityFocus ))]
namespace DependencyServiceDemos.iOS
{
    public class AndroidAccessibilityFocus : IAccessibilityFocusService
    {
        public void ChangeAccessibilityFocus(View v)
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

The registration work is being done with `[assembly: Dependency(typeof(AndroidAccessibilityFocus ))]`.

See [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction#register-the-platform-implementations) for more details.

Comment: Yes sorry, I did that but still doesn't work, no more error now, but it just doesn't change the focus. I edited the question. Do you know how to make it work?